# NDKでJNI内のcppにてstd,cvが名前解決できない

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

EclipseにてOpenCVのチュートリアル(OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing)をインポートしてコンパイルしようとしているのですが、
`jni_part.cpp`で `Symbol 'std' could not be resolved`, `Symbol 'cv' could not be resolved`
となってしまいます。

Application.mkでのAPP_STL指定は行っています

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse CDT](https://eclipse.org/cdt/)からビルドしているなら、英語版SO"[Eclipse CDT: Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803685/)"の回答が役立つかもしれません。